# Why I can't parse JSON decode response

Tags: php, json, curl

I would like some help me before asking I've tried in several ways and it don't works

Here is the JSON response I get

```
{
  "header": {
    "api_version": "3.0.0",
    "type_connection": 1,
    "user": "",
    "request_time": "2021-07-11 02:16:28",
    "access_ip": null,
    "error": null,
    },

        "result": [
            {
              "pessoa": ""{
                "cadastral": ""{
                  "number": "41259288231",
                  "tipoLogradouro": "AVENIDA",
              ]
    }}}]}
```

Here is the CURL

```
if (validNB($number)) {
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'localhost/cpf_json.php?token=235424343==&number='.$number.'',
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
'Cache-Control: no-cache',
'Connection: keep-alive',
'Pragma: no-cache',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Mobile Safari/537.36'
),
));

echo $Procurar = curl_exec($ch);
$json = json_decode($Procurar, true);
sleep($SleepTime);



$gettime = $json[0]['header']['request_time'];
$checkerror = $json[0]['header']['error'];
$logra = $json[0]['pessoa']['cadastral']['tipoLogradouro'];

if($checkerror == null){ 



    echo json_encode(array("status" => 1, "cartao" => 'Number: '.$number.' ', "separador" => '|',"retorno" => ' Test Get Time: '.$gettime.' | Test get error value: '.$checkerror.' test A error is null '));

} else {
    echo json_encode(array("status" => 0, "cartao" => 'Number: '.$number.' ', "separador" => ' ', "retorno" => ' Test Get Time: '.$gettime.' | Test get error value: '.$checkerror.' test B Error is not null | test logra: '.$logra.' '));
}
```

Something is wrong.
If I access manually URL I can see the response correctly, but the value of my string is not being shown on echo.
Any idea how to solve it?

My if echo currently is:

{"status":1,"cartao":"Number: ","separador":"|","retorno":" Test Get Time: | Test get error value: test A "}

No strings value has printted

Thanks in advance

Edit:

I can't print string values on echo encode =( Before that, this code has already worked. Even without close curl, I just took what already worked and modified it to parse this JSON response Don't know why it's not working, the fact of it do not show string values make me believe that is something when I'm trying get values.

According to the structure of the obtained JSON response, would this syntax be wrong?

```
$gettime = $json[0]['header']['request_time'];
$checkerror = $json[0]['header']['error'];
$logra = $json[0]['pessoa']['cadastral']['tipoLogradouro'];
```

This would explain why I can't print the value

Comment: Have you tried with `http://` at the start of your URL?

Comment: Yea! besides I can get the JSON return by putting an "echo" before $Procurar

Comment: Could you check for me if my json capture lines are correct according to the structure? I mean I can get "header > request time" value using $gettime = $json[0]['header']['request_time']; or it should be only $gettime = $json[0]['request_time']; ? Thanks

Comment: error_reporting() & json_last_error() are better substitutes for asking others to test.

Comment: Your JSON has multiple errors (the first one in your question).  Check it with something like https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Hello @mario. I'm sorry but it wasn't my intention to "ask others to test".

What I meant was just visually checking that my syntax was correct according to the structure of the JSON response.

Anyway, error_reporting() doesn't help me as I'm not getting any errors. Values are not printing most likely because they are not being retrieved successfully. Why? I'm trying to discover. 
Your answer was a very rude, thank you anyway <3

Comment: Can you share the output of developer console ? (Network Tab specifically). It may give you a clue if there is extra characters added in the output.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I've already solved @NicoHaase , thank you! the problem was in get values by $json because this sintax was wrong: ```$gettime = $json[0]['header']['request_time'];```

I've solved it, and answered the question <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Decode the json response correctly

```
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```

Then, pretty print your output

```
print("<pre>".print_r($json,true)."</pre>");
```

follow the sequence of arrays and objects to find the right sintax
in this case:

```
   "result": [
        {
          "pessoa": ""{
            "cadastral": ""{
              "number": "41259288231",
              "tipoLogradouro": "AVENIDA",
          ]
}}}]}
```

You can access this response values with:

```
$getnumber = $json['result'][0]['pessoa']['cadastral']['number'];
$gettipoLogradouro = $json['result'][0]['pessoa']['cadastral']['tipoLogradouro'];
```

I thank you for all the help you tried to give me, despite not solving the problem itself, it is necessary to recognize that the community is receptive and willing to help, as much as possible.